# What happens to my NSRunLoop and timer when the app goes into background and returns?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer, nsrunloop

I have an `NSRunLoop` in my app connected to a timer:

```
NSTimer *updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(onUpdateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:updateTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

When the app goes into background, what happens to this runloop?  Does it disappear, meaning I should recreate it in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should stop your timers when your app is suspended and restart them in `-applicationDidBecomeActive:`. See "What to Do When an Interruption Occurs" in [Responding to Interruptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW17). You don't have to worry about the run loop, though -- the OS will take care of that part.

Comment: Alright, so I don't need to manually stop the runloop.  Will I need to create one on applicationDidBecomeActive: using the same code?

Comment: No. Try it -- your run loop(s) should be fine.

Comment: Bear in mind that calls to being suspended and calls to applicationDidBecomeActive are not necessarily balaced one for one, so don't queue things willy nilly in applicationDidBecomeActive without some intelligence.